# Remove a set of specific characters from a string using Regular Expression

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group, nsregularexpression

How to remove all the occurrences of apostrophe('), hyphen(-) and dot(.) in a given string using Regular Expression?

For example: **John,. Home'Owner-New** should return **John, HomeOwnerNew**

I have tried using `name.replace("\'", "").replace("-", "").replace(".", "")` and it works. But I feel there should be a better approach using regular expression. I have tried few but with no luck. Can someone please guide me in the right direction?

Comment: `"".replace` accepts a regular expression. you're looking for `name.replace(/[-'.]/g, '')`. note that `-` has a special meaning inside character classes, so it must be either the first or last character. the `g` flag replaces all matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the regex you are looking for is likely `/[\.'-]/g`

I have attached a snippet including a test based on the sample you provided.

```js
const originalString = "John,. Home'Owner-New"
const expectedString = "John, HomeOwnerNew"
const myRegex = /[\.'-]/g
const newString = originalString.replace(myRegex, "");

const regexWorks = newString === expectedString;
if(!regexWorks) throw Error('test failed');

console.log({originalString});
console.log({newString});
```

Comment: Thanks Michael Sorensen. That works as expected!